# JSoup extract only specific parts from Wikipedia

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

I have managed to extract the information in the "tables" on the right side of a Wikipedia article. However I also want to get paragraphs from the main text of the articles.

The code I'm using atm is only working about 60% of the time(Nullpointers or no text at all). In the example below I'm only interested in the tho first paragraphs, however that is irrelevant for my question.

In the picture below I show what parts I want the text from. I want to be able to iterate through all

...

parts in the < divid="mw-content-text"....class="mw-content-ltr"> block.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String url = baseUrl + location;
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements paragraphs = doc.select(".mw-content-ltr  p");

    Element firstParagraph = paragraphs.first();
    Element elementTwo = firstParagraph.nextElementSibling();
    if (elementTwo == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            sb.append(paragraphs.get(i).text());

        }
    } else {
        sb.append(elementTwo.text());
    }

    return sb.toString();
```

[image]

Comment: No need to go that way. Wikipedia has an API that allows to query for pages: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API (ex. http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content)

Comment: Looks good, have you got any idea how a query would look for example get first and second paragraph from an article?

Comment: Well, you have to do some work on your own. If you're stuck somewhere feel free to come back and ask some questions.